# JUnit 5/Spring Boot - Use Properties but Mock Dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I'm trying to write unit tests for a DAO/Repository. My intent is to mock the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` object within and verify that the surrounding business logic doesn't do any bad (i.e.: handles nulls, etc...).

I'd also like to verify that the SQL is combined correctly. I can do this with `doAnswer(...)`, but the SQL queries live in a `.properties` file.

Is there a way to load a `.properties` file for testing, without loading all of the other dependencies of this class?

### What I've Tried

I've tried decorating the Test class with various permutations of :

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WidgetRepositoryImpl.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "sql.properties")
```

However, turning these on and off always seems to have one of the following effects:

- Load the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` as a bean. This *could* work if I specified the nearby `AppConfig` class in the `ContextConfiguration` annotation, but then I'd need to load *all* of its underlying dependencies, and the whole point is to *mock* this field.
- Load the Repository and mock the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, but not load `sql.properties`. The SQL statements are now null.

I want to avoid `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(widgetRepository, "namedParameterJdbcTemplate", "<put the sql here>")`. This works, but there are many SQL queries (the code below is very simplified). It also introduces a risk of human error (since now we're testing strings in the Test class, not the actual properties file.

### The question

**Is there any way to load `sql.properties` for this class, but not attempt to load the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?**

#### Unit Test

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "sql.properties")
class WidgetRepositoryImplTest  {

  @Mock
  private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private WidgetRepository widgetRepository;

  @Test
  public void testGetWidgetById() {
    // build a mock that returns a fake widget, and stores the SQL string for other tests
    doAnswer(invocation -> { ...omitted for brevity... }).when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate).query(anyString(), anyMap(), any(WidgetMapper.class));
    Widget widget = widgetRepository.getWidgetById("asdf-1234");
    assertNotNull(widget);
  }
```

#### Repository

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:sql.properties")
@Slf4j
@Repository
public class WidgetRepositoryImpl implements WidgetRepository {

  @Value("${widget-sql.selects.select-widget-by-id}")
  private String selectWidgetByIdQuery;

  @Autowired private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

  @Override
  public Widget getWidgetById(String id) {
    Map<String, String> params =  new HashMap<>();
    params.put("widgetId", id);
    List<Widget> results = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(selectWidgetByIdQuery, params, new WidgetMapper());

    if (results.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }

    return results.get(0);
  }
```

#### sql.properties

```
widget-sql.selects.select-widget-by-id=select * from [WIDGETS] where WIDGET_ID=:widgetId
# a few dozen additional queries in here
```

Comment: If you use `SpringExtension`, you can use the `@MockBean` annotation to mock a bean, similar to what `@Mock` does for `MockitoExtension`. You could use it to create a mocked implementation for the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: That's *exactly* what I was looking for: thank you! If you turn it into an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `SpringExtension` with the `@MockBean` annotation. This annotation will generate a mock implementation of the given class and provide it as a Spring bean. This means that if your class uses `@Autowired`, Spring will inject the mock for you:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // Make sure to use SpringExtension
@TestPropertySource(properties = "sql.properties")
class WidgetRepositoryImplTest  {

    @MockBean // Replace @Mock with @MockBean
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private WidgetRepository widgetRepository;

    // ...
}
```